# how to delete an element in xamarin forms webview

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webview

i want to delete an element in Xamarin.forms WebView when it's loading but it return null and app crash . how can i do this?
i tried to check if an element exist but dont have any success.
this is my code

```
protected void OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {



        Webview.Eval("const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(\"footer-section\"); while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();");


    }
```

please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null exception because the WebView is not loaded when you try to execute Javascript.

In order to prevent this, you can subscribe to [OnNavigated Event:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.webview.navigated?view=xamarin-forms)

> WebView.Navigated Event
>
> Event that is raised after navigation completes.

So, here is a sample:

```
public YourWebViewPage()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    Webview.Navigated += WebViewNavigated;
}

private void WebViewNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
   Webview.Eval("const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(\"footer-section\"); while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();");
}
```

Comment: i used it before but i want to delete that element when it disappear. i mean i don't want users see that element suddenly disappeared. i want to delete element right after that element shows and the page is still loading. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override function [onPageCommitVisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onPageCommitVisible(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) 
The Android documentation says:

> This callback can be used to determine the point at which it is safe
>   to make a recycled WebView visible, ensuring that no stale content is
>   shown. It is called at the earliest point at which it can be
>   guaranteed that WebView#onDraw will no longer draw any content from
>   previous navigations. The next draw will display either the
>   WebView#setBackgroundColor of the WebView, or some of the contents of
>   the newly loaded page.
>
> This method is called when the body of the HTTP response has started
>   loading, is reflected in the DOM, and will be visible in subsequent
>   draws. This callback occurs early in the document loading process, and
>   as such you should expect that linked resources (for example, CSS and
>   images) may not be available.

You can try the following code:

```
public override void OnPageCommitVisible(WebView view, string url)
     {
        string _javascript = "const elements = 
document.getElementsByClassName('footer-section'); for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++) { 
if(elements[i] != null){ elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]); }}";

        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
        base.OnPageCommitVisible(view, url);
    }
```

Comment: my app is Xamarin.Forms and i don't know how to use this code

Comment: You can try to achieve this by Cusom Renderer.For more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/